# Python dynamic processing of Oracle SDO_GEOMETRY objects

Tags: python, oracle, oracle-spatial, python-oracledb

There are some situations where the WKT format does not work  (3D,4D geometries, arc in a geodetic).
These are handled in Postgis EWKT format.

I have an out converter

```
def SDOOutConverter(DBobj):
    
  if DBobj.SDO_ELEM_INFO:
    sdo_elem = DBobj.SDO_ELEM_INFO.aslist()
  else:
    sdo_elem = None
      
  if DBobj.SDO_ORDINATES:
    sdo_ord = DBobj.SDO_ORDINATES.aslist()
  else:
    sdo_ord = None 
  return lSDO( 
    int(DBobj.SDO_GTYPE)
    ,DBobj.SDO_SRID
    ,sdo_elem
    ,sdo_ord
  )
```

and the object definition.

```
class lSDO(object):
  def __init__(self, gtype, srid, elemInfo, ordinates):
    self.gtype = gtype
    self.srid = int(srid or 0)
    self.elemInfo = elemInfo
    self.ordinates = ordinates
```

I have an example of returning the object information from a fixed query

```
cur.execute('select  mkt_id, name, shape from hamster.cola_markets t')
for time_id, name, obj in cur:
      sdo_type = obj.gtype
      sdo_srid = obj.srid
      sdo_elem = obj.elemInfo
      sdo_ord = obj.ordinates
```

This takes the geometry column (shape) then in the for loop access the object.

Question:
How would i do this dynamically.
There are several tables with differing structures.

how would I write a dynamic
for time_id, name, obj in cur:?

bonus question,  How would one handle a table with multiple GEOMETRY columns?

I can crate a column list and tried using the string in the for loop

```
for '{}'.format(objcol) in cur:
```

results in:

```
   for '{}'.format(objcol) in cur:
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is:
replacing

```
cur.execute('select  mkt_id, name, shape from hamster.cola_markets t')
for time_id, name, obj in cur:
```

with:

```
cur.execute('select * from {}.{}'.format(schema,tablename))
for [dynamic column list with obj reference] in cur:
```

In other words handle cursor procession dynamically.

Comment: Does `dumpobject()` in [bind_sdo.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/blob/main/samples/tutorial/solutions/bind_sdo.py) help?

Comment: No, I've added an edit to clarify what I want to do.

Comment: You make reference to an output converter but I don't see the code where it is configured. Can you supply that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to partially answer my own question.

Part of my confusion is from the examples for sdo_geometries, without  clear explanations.

With further experimenting i discovered that

```
cur.execute('select  mkt_id, name, shape from hamster.cola_markets t')
for time_id, name, obj in cur:
```

is misleading.
obj is just an alias for shape, so

```
sdo_type = obj.gtype
```

would work as well as

```
sdo_type = shape.gtype
```

So the problem for me was attributing some special meaning to obj, when what is does, at least for me, is obfuscates what is actually going on.

Documenting what is going on in code is helpful.